# Simulated-trials probability not converging to theoretical probability

Tags: probability

Premise: Person A picks five letters (no repeats) of the standard English alphabet (26 letters). Six other people (persons B-G) are asked to independently pick (privately write on a piece of paper) one letter of the alphabet. Since these picks are independent, it is possible to have repeats in this set.

The task at hand is to calculate the probability that at least one of persons B-G has picked a letter that matches one of the letters picked by person A.

Theoretically, since this probability should be equal to the complement of the probability that none of persons B-G picked a matching letter:

P(at least one match in 6 tries) = 1 - P(no matches in six tries)
                      = 1 - (6C6) * P(not getting a match in a single trial)^6
                      = 1- 1 * (21/26)^6
                      = 0.7224

I set out to generate one million simulated random trials to examine the empirical probability, with the hope that it would come close to the theoretical probability calculated above. My procedure was as follows:

1. To simulate the action of person A, used MATLAB to generate one million trials of five unique random numbers between 1 to 26, inclusive:

`for i=1:1000000
    data1(i,:)=randperm(26,5);
end`

2. To simulate the actions of persons B-G, I once again used MATLAB to generate one million trials of six random numbers (no unique-number restriction) between 1 to 26, inclusive:

`data2 = randi([1 26],1000000,6);`

3. I quality-checked the data, found that all constraints were satisfied, then exported it to Excel, matching each trial from data set one with a trial from data set two.
4. Noting that person A's letter picks are stored in Excel columns A-E, and persons B-G's picks are stored in columns G-L (skipped column F as a divider),  I created a column in Excel that used the following logic to examine each row:

`=IF(OR(A1=G1,A1=H1,A1=I1,A1=J1,A1=K1,A1=L1,B1=G1,B1=H1,B1=I1,B1=J1,B1=K1,B1=L1,C1=G1,C1=H1,C1=I1,C1=J1,C1=K1,C1=L1,D1=G1,D1=H1,D1=I1,D1=J1,D1=K1,D1=L1,E1=G1,E1=H1,E1=I1,E1=J1,E1=K1,E1=L1),1,0)`

**NOTE: above code was edited as per user:lulu's comment below**

4. I once again quality-checked the results. If one or more of person's B-G's picks matched, the analysis column (column M) displayed a "1". Otherwise, it displayed a zero. Working as intended.
5. In order to compute the empirical probability, I performed the following calculation in a separate cell:

`=SUM(M:M)/COUNT(M:M)`

To my disappointment, the value was 0.67155. I repeated the entire simulation seven more times, and ended up with values of {0.67149, 0.67161, 0.67131, 0.67092, 0.67190, 0.67116, and 0.67126}. This would seem to suggest that the probability is converging to somewhere just above 0.67.

**NOTE: with above edit in step 4, for one set of trials, I recomputed to 0.6783. Closer, but still off.**

My question is: Is this discrepancy between the theoretical and empirical probabilities due to:

1. An issue with my simulation methodology in that I incorrectly represented the premises of the initial situation?
2. An issue with the simulation methodology in that I did not perform enough trials? (I am doubtful of this one)
3. An issue with the pseudorandom number generation?
4. An incorrect assessment and computation of the theoretical probability?
5. Anything else I have not considered?

I would very much appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: You should generally be suspicious of *permutation* generators, because standard pseudorandom number generators have a period much shorter than $n!$ for even moderately large $n$.

Comment: Matlab's `randperm` and `randi` are based on Mersenne Twister with a period of $2^{19937}-1$ by default, which is muuuch larger than $n!$ in this case.

Comment: Your code appears to check $B1=L1$ twice, while it never checks $A1=L1$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for that! I pored over the code and did not see that. Always great to have a fresh pair of eyes. With that fix, I recomputed, and got a value of 0.6783 for the empirical probability. A bit closer at least.

Comment: @horchler Just to clarify, your comment is evidence against what Ian proposed as a potential issue?

Comment: Absolutely. There is no issue with the random number generators or how you're generating your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are not doing everything in Matlab (or how you're moving the data over to Excel, which could introduce errors if you're not careful). In pure Matlab:

```
rng(1); % Set seed to be able to replicate
n = 1e6;
data1 = zeros(n,5);
for i = 1:n
    data1(i,:) = randperm(26,5);
end
data2 = randi([1 26],n,6);
```

Then, using a double `for` loop for clarity:

```
s = 0;
v = zeros(5,1);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:5
        v(j) = any(data1(i,j)==data2(i,:));
    end
    s = s+any(v);
end
p = s/n
```

This returns `0.721587`, which is approximately $1-(21/26)^6 = 0.722364062753467...$. Different initial seed will result in different outputs. The double `for` loop could be vectorized to:

```
data3 = zeros(n,5);
for i = 1:5
    data3(:,i) = any(bsxfun(@eq,data1(:,i),data2),2);
end
p = sum(any(data3,2))/n
```

Given this, I'd say the issue is in your Excel code and/or which rows and columns are being used. Did you fill down column M correctly, i.e., do the indices correspond to the row correctly? It's hard to say more without seeing your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was trying to do everything in Excel initially, as I am not as familiar with MATLAB, then I realized I couldn't easily generate unique random numbers in Excel.

To answer your question, yes, I autofilled the "M" column down by double clicking the bottom right corner of the initial cells, and I checked several cells throughout the simulation. They checked out. Is there any appropriate way I can share my spreadsheet file on Stackexchange?

Comment: @meiso: How di you get the data from Matlab to Excel? If it was copy-pasted, then I'd suspect your data might not be what you expect. I also would never use Excel's random number generator for any mathematical/scientific work.

Comment: Yes, I did copy-paste, column by column, from MATLAB's variable viewer (double-clicked under Workspace). I did go to several random rows in the Excel spreadsheet after doing this to make sure numbers were between 1 and 26 inclusive, edge cases appeared, and there were no repeats in person A's selections (randperm). This all seemed to check out. So, if the data did change somewhat, if all the constraints were followed, how exactly might the numbers changing to other numbers that still followed the constraints affect the computed probability?

Comment: Tried again, copying and pasting much more carefully. Now getting 0.722848 for empirical probability. Thank you for the pure MATLAB method and the caveats regarding Excel and copy-pasting data.